# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'm:'

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

I'm getting an error for the else statement but not for the if statement, and they are supposed to be the same. I'm not able to point out why there is an error.

Here is the error:

```
line 27, in <module>
Y.append(int(i))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'm:'
```

And here is the code, I still didn't finish it, I'm still checking out the errors:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Y=mX+c Graph")

def startfunc():
    string =''
    for x in Y:
        string = string+ str(x) +'\n'
        my_label.config(text=string)

X=[]
Y=[]

for x in range(2):
    e = Entry(root)
    e.grid(row=0, column=x, padx=5, pady=10)
    if(x==1):
        e.insert(0,"X:")
        i = e.get()
        i.lstrip(":")
        X.append(int(i))
    else:
        e.insert(0,"m:")
        i = e.get()
        i.lstrip(":")
        Y.append(int(i))

button = Button(root, text="Start", command=startfunc)
button.grid(row=0,column =3,padx=5,pady=10)
my_label = Label(root,text='')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You enter `m:` in the Entry widget (`e.insert(0,"m:")`) then you get the value `'m:'` and try to strip the colon from the wrong side. Then you try to convert `m:` to int. What do you expect to happen? You will get similar problem with the other Entry widget too, it just happen that x value in first iteration is 0.

Comment: I guess you want to do `i = i.lstrip(":")`, which is wrongly written just as `i.lstrip(":")`.

Comment: you could use `tk.Label` to display text `m:` before `Entry` and then you don't have to put it in `Entry` and you don't have to remove it from string before converting to `integer`.

Comment: `Entry` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for data - so using `e.get()` directly after creating `Entry()` get value when you create this widget, not when you put data in Entry. You should first only create `Entry` and you should get value in `startfunc`

Comment: simply use `print(i)` before line which makes problem and you should see that you have wrong text in variable - `m:` . `lstrip(':')` removes `:` only if it first char but you have `:` at second place and you should ratehrn use `i = i[2:]` to skip two chars `m:`

Comment: Thank you @furas I didn't know that about the get function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lstrip(':')` removes `:` only if it at the beginning of string but you have `:` as second char. Maybe you need `split(":")` to create two strings - before `:` and after `:`. OR maybe you should slice it `i = i[2:]` to remove two chars from the beginning.

But there is other problem. `Entry` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your data. It only informs `tkinter` what it has to display in window. If you use `get()` directly after `Entry` then you get empty string or only `"m:"`. You have to use `.get()` in `startfunc`

---

**Minimial working example.**

I put `X:`, `m:` as `Labels` above `Entry` so I don't have to remove it from value which I get from `Entry`.

For two `Entries` it is simpler to create them without `for`-loop. And code is more readable.

But if you would have more `Entries` then I would use `for`-loop with `list` or `tuple` instead of `range()`

```
for number, text in enumerate(["X:", "m:"]):
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# -- functions ---

def startfunc():
    new_x = entry_x.get()
    new_m = entry_m.get()
    
    X.append(int(new_x))
    Y.append(int(new_m))

    string = "\n".join([str(i) for i in X])
    label_x.config(text=string)
    
    string = "\n".join([str(i) for i in Y])
    label_m.config(text=string)

# --- main ---

X = []  # PEP8: spaces around `=`
Y = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Y=mX+c Graph")

# ---

l = tk.Label(root, text="X:")
l.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

entry_x = tk.Entry(root)
entry_x.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

l = tk.Label(root, text="m:")
l.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

entry_m = tk.Entry(root)
entry_m.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

# ---

button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=startfunc)
button.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)

# ---

label_x = tk.Label(root)
label_x.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

label_m = tk.Label(root)
label_m.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really helpful